# KQL Syntax using a variable - Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange-server

This works as expected:

```
Search-Mailbox jdoe -SearchQuery 'sent:"today" AND subject:"1234"' -EstimateResultOnly
```

It returns 1 result as it should.

Trying to replace *1234* with a variable but in vain.  I figure it's an issue with my syntax but I've tried just about every combination of quotes and doublequotes and still it doesnt return anything.

```
$subject = "1234"
Search-Mailbox jdoe -SearchQuery {'sent:"today" AND subject:"'$subject'"'} -EstimateResultOnly
```

How can I replace "1234" with a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Because {'sent:"today" AND subject:"'$subject'"'} is a scriptblock http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/05/22/variable-substitution-in-a-powershell-script-block.aspx your varible won't expand. So you just need to construct the script block like

```
$Varible = "1234"
$Search = [scriptblock]::create("'sent:`"today`" AND subject:$Varible'")
Search-Mailbox jdoe -SearchQuery $Search -EstimateResultOnly
```

Cheers
Glen